# DbContext not found in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I'm creating a web application using `Visual Studio 2012` and `Framework 4.5` and I'm using `MVC 4` and I'm stuck with a problem.

I need to use `DbContext`  but I'cant find that in my project means I added System.Data.Entity and it still gives an error

> The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I solve this...?

Comment: Did you forgot to install EF from [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0)?

Comment: @CuongLe nope Its already there

Comment: @AlenJoy Have you added `DBML` File to your project..? The `DBML` Name should same as `DbContext`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `DbContext` lives in `EntityFramework.dll`. [See this for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

You can get it from nuget by typing this command in the PMC

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0
```

You can get into the PMC by going to *Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console* in VS

Comment: I am doing the MusicStore tutorial of the MVC and encountered the error that DbContext and DbSet are missing the refference. This solutions works perfect! Thank you mister @vonv.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the accepted answer, this may help people in a situation that has not yet been mentioned:

This problem occurred for me when I created a new mvc4 project in an *existing* Solution in Visual Studio 2012. The Solution already contained a working mvc4 project, but when I created the second project it could not find the System.Data.Entity package (including DbContext). The install-package command does not solve the problem in this situation, because the overall Solution already had the package installed:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
'EntityFramework 6.0.1' already installed.
```

The problem was that the EntityFramework package does not get automatically installed in new projects, you have to add it manually. Go to:

```
Tools -> Library Package Manager -> "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..."
```

Search for EntityFramework in the box at the top right, click Manage, and then check the box for the new solution. The new project should now build correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that through the following steps :

**Right-click your Project** in the Solutions Explorer.

**Choose Add Reference...**

Look for the **System.Data.Entity.dll** file (or the **EntityFramework.dll**) and add them to your Project.

You can also accomplish the same thing through NuGet if you have it installed :

**Right-click your Project** in the Solutions Explorer.

**Choose Manage NuGet Packages...**

Search for the **EntityFramework** Package.

Click Install to add it to your existing project.

After you have successfully added these to your application, you'll just need to add a using statement within the page that you are using your DbContext and DbSet objects on :

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

[Reference Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1892907.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue, and it didn't work until i've installed EntityFramework from menu -> Project -> Manage Nuget Packages...

Answer (score 0):

DbContext is part of EntityFramework.dll and not System.Data.Entity.

It was introduced in EF 4.1. You can install appropriate NuGet package using visual studio 2012. e.g. Right click on Project and select "Manange NuGet Packages" and find appropriate EF version and install it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred for me when I created a new mvc4 project in an existing Solution in `Visual Studio 2012`. The Solution already contained a working `mvc4` project, but when I created the second project it could not find the `System.Data.Entity package` (including DbContext). The `install-package` command does not solve the problem in this situation, because the overall Solution already had the package installed:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
'EntityFramework 6.0.1' already installed.
```

The problem was that the EntityFramework package does not get automatically installed in new projects, you have to add it manually. Go to:

```
Tools -> Library Package Manager -> "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..."
```

Search for EntityFramework in the box at the top right, click Manage, and then check the box for the new solution. The new project should now build correctly.